# cant get cookie value

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I dont understand why I can't get my cookie?

> $rootScopt.globals.currentUser = undefined

```
angular.module('MyModule', [
    'Authentication',
    'Home',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies'
])
.config([
    //Config
])
.run([
    '$rootScope', '$location', '$cookies', '$http',
    function($rootScope, $location, $cookies, $http) {
        //Keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals = {
            currentUser: {
                username: "foo",
                password: "bar"
            }
        }

        $cookies.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);

        $rootScope.globals = $cookies.get('globals') || {};



        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) { //Never go in here..
            //Do stuff
        }
    }
]);
```

I've checked that my cookie get stored, and it seems to work fine. But when trying to get my cookie it doesn't work..Anyone now why?

Comment: what browser are u using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Chrome doesn't allow cookies for local files. You have to run it with the --enable-file-cookies flag.

Try this way:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12wnv163/)

```
    angular.module('test',['ngCookies'])
  .run(function($rootScope, $cookies){
     $rootScope.globals = {
            currentUser: {
                username: "foo",
                password: "bar"
            }
        }
   $cookies.put('globals', JSON.stringify($rootScope.globals));
    var a = $cookies.get('globals');
    $rootScope.globals = JSON.parse(a) || {}
    console.log($rootScope.globals);
})
```

Comment: But I can see that the cookie is stored..?